# Capture the html canvas for processing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am running small projects that requires to capture and analyse the content of the canvas.

It is an agent which plays google [no-internet dinosaur game](http://www.trex-game.skipser.com/).

I can access content of the canvas from a console with:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,600,150);
```

But I have been trying to use `HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream()` to generate the event at a given framerate or whenever the canvas changes.

But when I implement it as:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
const stream = canvas.captureStream(25)
stream.onaddtrack = function(event) { console.log("Called") }
```

I would expect the `console.log("Called")` to be called 25 times per second, but nothing gets called. Have I misunderstood something about the streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream returns a MediaStream. This MediaStream is initially composed of a special kind of [MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack): a [CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack) which is simply a special video track with a link to the original HTMLCanvasElement.

This may still sound foreign language at this stage...
A MediaStream is a container object holding tracks themselves holding a stream of raw data, which are part of a media. An audio track will hold a stream of raw audio data, a video or canvas one will hold a stream of raw video data.

Tracks can be added or removed from a MediaStream, so that the MediaStream that was fed by a webcam's video be changed to a video coming webRTC etc. This is what the the `onaddtrack` event monitors: when a MediaStreamTrack is added to the MediaStream container.
It has nothing to do with frames being appended to the video stream, for the MediaStream, it is either *streaming* or *paused*.

So your MediaStream holds a stream of video data, generated from the canvas current state.
Captured stream from canvas have this special that you can require at which **maximum** frequency the browser should append new frames to 
the video stream. However this is just a maximum; if nothing new has been painted on the canvas, then no image will get appended, and the stream will continue to display the last image that got appended.

I don't think there is any way to know when this operation happens, but even if there was one, your process would be too much convoluted.

1. draw on canvas1
2. capture stream
3. render stream in <video>
4. draw <video> on canvas2
5. process the image drawn on canvas2

While all you need is

1. draw on canvas1
2. process the image drawn on canvas1

If you want to do it at a certain frame-rate, then set up a timeout loop.

Comment: Cheers, Makes a lot of sense I will go with timeout loop approach.

Comment: This is really cool in therory but can you show some code or a small demo of it working? I am currently trying to capture a canvas at 30 fps but drop frames. Thanks